# Keep getting "undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass" what am I doing wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, sendgrid

So this is what my controller looks like. I want to click a button and have an email be sent to the email in the current quote. If I put a string email in there it works, but when I swap it to have a @quote.email grabbing the email from the current object it gives me this error:

"undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass"

I have no idea why this is doing this, someone please help!

```
class QuotesController < ApplicationController

  require 'sendgrid-ruby'
  include SendGrid

  before_action :set_quote, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /quotes
  # GET /quotes.json
  def index
    @quotes = Quote.all
  end

  def thankyoupage
  end

  # GET /quotes/1
  # GET /quotes/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /quotes/new
  def new
    @quote = Quote.new
  end

  # GET /quotes/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /quotes
  # POST /quotes.json
  def create

    @quote = Quote.new(quote_params)

    if @quote.save
      redirect_to thankyou_path
    else
      redirect_to root
    end

  end

  # PATCH/PUT /quotes/1
  # PATCH/PUT /quotes/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @quote.update(quote_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @quote, notice: 'Quote was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @quote }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @quote.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /quotes/1
  # DELETE /quotes/1.json
  def destroy
    @quote.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to quotes_url, notice: 'Quote was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def sendQuoteEmail

    from = SendGrid::Email.new(email: 'email@joinbennett.com')
    to = SendGrid::Email.new(email: @quote.email)
    subject = 'Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun'
    content = SendGrid::Content.new(type: 'text/plain', value: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Ruby')
    mail = SendGrid::Mail.new(from, subject, to, content)

    sg = SendGrid::API.new(api_key: '*****************')
    response = sg.client.mail._('send').post(request_body: mail.to_json)
    puts response.status_code
    puts response.body
    puts response.headers

  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_quote
      @quote = Quote.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def quote_params
      params.fetch(:quote, {}).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :phone_number, :address, :email, :quote_date, :quote_time, :quote_bedroom, :quote_bathroom, :quote_notes, :quote_price, :quote_price_recurring)
    end
end
```

When a Quote is created it has an email. I've created this button to run this action called SendQuoteEmail.

```
<%= button_to 'Send Quote Email', quotes_sendQuoteEmail_path, method: :post, class: 'btn btn-success mt-3' %>
```

What am I doing wrong? I keeps saying the @quote.email is NIL??

Comment: Note: Ruby is a case-sensitive language and capital letters have specific meaning in terms of syntax. Variables and method names should be lower-case letters. Capitals indicate constants of the form  `ClassName` or `CONSTANT_NAME`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your controller, update this line:

```
before_action :set_quote, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :sendQuoteEmail]
```

then in your view, pass the id. quotes_sendQuoteEmail_path(:id => @quote.id)

```
<%= button_to 'Send Quote Email', quotes_sendQuoteEmail_path(:id => @quote.id), method: :post, class: 'btn btn-success mt-3' %>
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you! ☺️

Answer (score 1):

Change your:

```
  before_action :set_quote, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

to

```
  before_action :set_quote, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, : sendQuoteEmail]
```

This will let Rails run `set_quote` method which will enable controller to find `@quote` object before you act on it.

Add `@quote` in path helper:

```
<%= button_to 'Send Quote Email', quotes_sendQuoteEmail_path(@quote) ...
```

Comment: This worked, but I still needed to add 
<%= button_to 'Send Quote Email', quotes_sendQuoteEmail_path(:id => @quote.id), method: :post, class: 'btn btn-success mt-3' %>

Comment: just path the `@quote` instead of `:id => @quote.id`. See update in answer. It automatically passes the primary key of the model as key, value